# Generating Table with random Numbers from 1 to 100.000.000 without any doubles in a short amount of time

Tags: c++, qt, random, generator

for a Project do I need to create a Table that stores 100.000.000 Numbers in a random Order without any doubles, which then get saved as .csv File.

```
void Anonym_Option::GenerateTable(){
    ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
    QList<int> l(100000000);
    std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), 0);

    QVector<QList<int>::iterator> v(l.size());
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());

    ui->progressBar->setValue(10);

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine {seed};

    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), rng);

    QString SortString;
    QString CombinedString;

    ui->progressBar->setValue(30);

    for (auto z: v){
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        SortString += QString::number(*z) + "," + "\n";
    }

    ui->progressBar->setValue(70);

    CombinedString = SortString.replace(QString("\n;"), QString("\n"));

    QString Table = "Generated ID; \n" + CombinedString;

    ui->progressBar->setValue(90);

    QString Path = QDir::currentPath();
    QFile file(Path + "/Table.csv");
    if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "ACHTUNG","ACHTUNG! Der Anonymisierungs-Table kann nicht generiert werden! Bitte Kontaktieren sie den Support.");
        return;
    }
    else{
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        stream << Table;
        ui->progressBar->setValue(100);
        hide();
        anonymisierung = new Anonymisierung();
        QTimer::singleShot(1500,anonymisierung,SLOT(show()));
    }
}
```

The purpose of that Table is to replace Numbers in the Customer File, so that it's anonymised.
The Problem I have with my Code is that while if I use 10.000.000 Numbers does it take around 8 Min to get done,but when I use 100.000.000 does it seem to take more RAM and Time than it is practical. The Problem could I localize in this Function

```
    for (auto z: v){
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        SortString += QString::number(*z) + "," + "\n";
    }
```

which whole purpose is to add a "," and "\n" after each Number, so that it does get seperated accordingly and can be used later on.
Any Ideas how to fasten up the Progress?

TL;DR I use QT6 in hope for Ranges, sadly not implemented yet, so not an Option I can use!

Comment: Have you thought about using a separate thread rather than manually calling `processEvents`?

Comment: First of all, avoid reallocations. I don't know `QString`, however `SortString += ...` probably reallocates many many times, what forces `QStringt` to copy the data everytime it reallocates. Second, why don't you just write directly into the file and let the OS decide when to flush? I think this should give you a big boost.

Comment: You could easily eliminate the RAM usage by avoiding storing your values in multiple QStrings. You could write to the file directly inside your loop.

Comment: You are likely looking for this.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#reserve

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle is linear in complexity

Comment: If neither of the current answers fits the bill, can you say why?  Otherwise, you should consider "accepting" one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing the keys, then a shuffle is just as fast. I tried to keep as much as possible similar, but when shuffling, a `std::linear_congruential_engine` both doesn't make sense and it took ~4 times longer.

I include both methods so you can comment out and test them yourself. While not super-scientific, my shell prompt shows a time to execute, and both methods show 10s. I'm executing in WSL with files stored in Windows-land.

My compiler flags: `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++17`

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  constexpr std::uint32_t upper = 100'000'000;
  std::vector<std::uint32_t> rando(upper);

  std::iota(rando.begin(), rando.end(), 1);
  std::shuffle(rando.begin(), rando.end(),
               std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

  for (std::uint32_t i = 345; i < 355; ++i) {
    std::cout << rando[i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

// #include <iostream>
// #include <vector>

// int main()
// {
//     constexpr std::uint32_t upper = 100000000;
//     std::vector<std::uint32_t> rando;
//     rando.reserve(upper);

//     std::uint32_t I = 128;
//     for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i <= upper;){
//         I = 1664525 * I + 1013904223;
//         if (I <= upper){
//             rando.push_back(I);
//             ++i;
//         }
//     }

//     for (int i = 345; i < 355; ++i) {
//         std::cout << rando[i] << ' ';
//     }
//     std::cout << '\n';
// }
```

Comment: I do think the shuffle solution is way more maintainable than the second one.

Comment: @sweenish You code looks good, but I have a Question. The `for`-Loop is for the writing if I see it right. You tested it with only 10 Numbers? Since I need to write 100'000'000 to the file and running your Program adjusted with the `for`-Loop consumes up to 1GB RAM and the time it takes is about 9 Min long. Did I do something wrong or is my writing speed just being my limitation here?

Comment: To plainly answer your question, the writing speed is the limitation. My `for` loop only prints 10 numbers, but the entire vector is generated and shuffled. I added that loop in case the compiler decided to optimize everything away since I otherwise never accessed it. Printing the entire thing to the screen or a file will take longer. This code demonstrates the time to generate what you want, not to write it out. It also goes to show that the efficiency of the generation was never going to be your bottleneck, but the I/O.

Answer (score 2):

A shuffling approach may well require you to keep the array in a contiguous block of memory, which might not be feasible for a large number of elements.

However, if your degree of randomness needs to be no better than a typical implementation of `rand()` then you can use a linear congruential generator, which has the property that it doesn't repeat until the *periodicity* is reached, and don't include the numbers outside the range.

The following program runs in under a second on my machine, and will produce a file that includes all the numbers in the range [0, 100000000] without repeats.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::uint32_t upper = 100000000;
    std::uint32_t I = 128;
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i <= upper;){
        I = 1664525 * I + 1013904223;
        if (I <= upper){
            std::cout << I << "\n";
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Choose the initial value of `I` (the *seed*) based on your system time clock.

The magic numbers in the congruential step are down to that remarkable scientific programmer Donald Knuth.

Comment: random shuffle is linear in complexity https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` has been removed as of C++17. Use `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: I'll revise. I still think this approach is better.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no repeats?  I’m dubious -- a decent 32 bit LCG won’t repeat its state until it cycles, but there are definitely repeats of subsets of the bits corresponding to values less than 100M.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but I'll chime in that a shuffle on my computer (i5 Haswell) took ~6 seconds. The code was compiled with `-O2`. I declared a vector with the size needed, used `std::iota` to fill, and then shuffled with `std::mt19937`. There are savings to be had with this approach, but I'm not going to post as an answer unless I can get similar performance.

Comment: @pjs: Inserting the values into a `std::set<std::uint32_t>` yields a set of size upper  + 1. This proves the approach for any seed less than or equal to `upper`.

Comment: Agreed that setting will guarantee the uniqueness, but that requires its own checking for uniqueness and increases the number of iterations, both of which will cause it to be slower than the simple loop you've written.

Comment: @pjs: No, No, No. You don't need to maintain the `std::set`, that was to verify. Use the code as above. The uniqueness is guaranteed. You're correct in saying that some sets of magic numbers produces a subgroup (there's nice proof somewhere based on some work Lagrange did - I have a copy in my library in Devon), but the ones I present don't.

Comment: Ah!  You're saying you did a posterior test to check uniqueness based on the seed value 128.  Well okay then.